# Spring-hadoop job-runner issue in seeting java system parameters

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

I have to run the following command from spring-data-hadopp

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/ubuntu/recommendation.jar 
org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob 
-Dmapred.input.dir=input/testDataFileModel.csv -Dmapred.output.dir=outputItem --usersFile 
input/users.txt --booleanData true --similarityClassname 
org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.similarity.cooccurrence.measures.LoglikelihoodSimilarity
```

So I am using

```
<jar-runner jar="recommender-engine-mapred-1.0.jar" main-class="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob" run-at-startup="true" pre-action="setupScript" configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration">
    <arg value="-s org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.similarity.cooccurrence.measures.LoglikelihoodSimilarity"/>        
            <arg value="-b true"/>
        mapred.input.dir=${wordcount.input.path}testDataFileModel.csv
        mapred.output.dir=${wordcount.output.path}

</jar-runner>
```

But I am getting following error message:- 
2014-02-11 15:53:07,585 ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-5 org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob.parseArguments:363 - No input specified or -Dmapred.input.dir must be provided to specify input directory

How Can I pass the system arguments in spring-hadoop job-runner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure by specifying a file name instead of directory's name?

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
-Dmapred.input.dir=input/testDataFileModel.csv

mapred.input.dir=${wordcount.input.path}testDataFileModel.csv
```

Try to set ***-Dmapred.input.dir*** to the real dir where your file is in.

Hadoop is smart enough to iterate over all the files in the directory (not recursively, you have to configure it to do so).

Comment: What you are saying is working fine if I run this command from shell I as I have mentioned. But I have to use spring-data-hadoop to run the command. And ${wordcount.input.path} is the variable which is set in spring-context file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run this in following manner.

I have created main function which use ToolRunner to call this job.

```
public class ItemSimilarityJobRunner {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ToolRunner.run(new RecommenderJob(), args);
    }

}
```

Now I create a jar and running this jar using following tags in spring-data-hadoop.

```
<jar-runner jar="recommender-engine-mapred-1.0.jar" main-class="tarun.tool.ItemSimilarityJobRunner" 
        run-at-startup="true" pre-action="setupScript" post-action="exportJobResulDataScript">
        <arg value="-btrue"/>
        <arg value="-sorg.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.similarity.cooccurrence.measures.LoglikelihoodSimilarity"/>
        mapred.input.dir=${hdfs.path.prefix}/input
        mapred.output.dir=${hdfs.path.prefix}/output
    </jar-runner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<jar-runner jar="recommender-engine-mapred-1.0.jar" main-class="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob" run-at-startup="true" pre-action="setupScript" configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration">
        <arg value="-btrue"/>
        <arg value="-sorg.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.similarity.cooccurrence.measures.LoglikelihoodSimilarity"/>
        <arg value="-i${wordcount.input.path}"/>
        <arg value="-o${wordcount.input.path}"/>    
</jar-runner>
```

This is how you pass on the parameters (< arg / >). Be careful not to put space after the '-b,-s,-i,-o' characters, because I have found that it makes a difference with and without space (it worked for me only without space).